# Javascript/jquery works in every browser except firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox

This code works in IE8, Crome and Safari, but not in firefox:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">
        alert("wazzup");
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".MathLink").hover(function () {
                $(this).css("color", "#d7d7d7");
            }, function () {
                $(this).css("color", "#FFFFFF");
            });

            $("#betyg_textblock").click(function () {
                window.open("http://hogrebetyg.se/");
            })

            $("#roids_textblock").click(function () {
                window.open("http://www.kongregate.com/games/irradiance_se/roids?acomplete=roids");
            })

            $(".servicesDiv").mouseenter(function (event) {

                if ($(this).css("height") == "45px") {
                    $(".servicesDiv").animate({
                        height: "45px"
                    }, 300);

                    $(this).animate({
                        height: "100px"
                    }, 300, function () {
                        $(".servicesDiv").clearQueue();
                    });
                }
            });

            $(".news").click(function (event) {
                if ($(this).css("height") == "53px") {
                    $(this).animate({
                        height: "100%"
                    }, 400, function () {
                        $(".news").clearQueue();

                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).animate({
                        height: "53px"
                    }, 400, function () {
                        $(".news").clearQueue();

                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have no idea why. Please help.

Comment: Which part is not working? what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Could it be related to the dodgy script tag? `<script type="text/jscript">`? Try `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: check Firefox whether java script enable or disable.

Comment: Install Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) check what errors are displayed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the following:

**text/javascript**

Opera 7.54+

IE 5+

Firefox 1.0.7+

Safari 2.0.3+

iCab 3 Beta 394

Camino 2006021400

**text/jscript**

Opera 7.54+

IE 5+

Safari 2.0.3+

**Change it to** `text/javascript`

Ref: http://sachabarber.net/?p=824 AND http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/javascript/mime-types/

e.g.

```
<script type="text/jscript"> /*Code*/ </script>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript"> /*Code*/ </script>
```

Comment: +1 Nice. Thought that was the problem, but was struggling to find a concrete reference.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Karim79. Well spotted, I actually miss-read the code at first, Coz I had the same problem not so long ago.